# 2.78a cannot see Numpy - Win7 - 64bit

Tags: add-on, installation

first post here.

Fresh install of 2.78a on Win7 64bit. Cleaned out Environment paths. Deleted old Python installs.

Trying to get Animation Nodes to work but it can't see Numpy.

In the Blender console Blender can't see Numpy either. But it is obviously looking in the right path \scripts\modules\numpy

[image: Blender 2.78a Win 64bit Numpy not found]

I'd appreciate any help or notifications of or allusions to significant cognitive failure.

Cheers!

added greeting

Comment: I have the same issue with OSX 64bit 2.78 build bot.